# $\gcd\left(\lfloor x+1\rfloor+1,2^{\lfloor x\rfloor}+1\right)$ has a similar structure to the Sierpinski's triangle. Is it a fractal?

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, ceiling-and-floor-functions, fractals

Working on a deleted question, I found a similar structure to the Sierpinski's triangle this is:

$$\gcd\left(\lfloor x+1\rfloor+1,2^{\lfloor x\rfloor}+1\right)$$

[image: triangle]

Is it a fractal? Does it have nice properties as it could be related to prime number?

Comment: The behaviour can also be described , if $x$ is a positive integer and the floor-function ignored. Have you checked , whether the emerging sequence exhibits a clear pattern ? I have doubts.

Comment: @Peter Dear , I suspect there is a subset of prime number such that  $gcd=1$ and a connection with the representation as a sum of two square (hypothenuse too). Try 97,677 for example .The triangles verify a dilation also.

Comment: How do you define "fractal"?  If it *is* a fractal, so what?  What do you gain (or lose) by calling it "fractal"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sadly, it seems like Desmos (if it is indeed desmos you used), lied to you.

To clearly expose it, let's define $f : n \mapsto \gcd(n + 2, 2^n + 1)$, which is the function you plotted on the image.

If we take the highest point on the image, (namely at $n=190$), Desmos indeed says that we have $f(190) = 64$, but the truth is that $f(190) = 1$.
Indeed, $190 + 2 = 192 = 2^6 \cdot 3$, and it is obvious that $2^6$ does not divide $2^{190} + 1$, neither does $3$, as can be found with some modular arithmetic.

So Desmos is most likely giving false results because of overflows, and to be fair, the same 'fractal' seems to be here for most plots of the form $\gcd(an + b, 2^n +1)$ for $a, b \in \mathbb N$. (You can test that for yourself).

---

I plotted the correct results with `matplotlib`, and sadly it seems like the pattern disappeared.

[image: Image plot for values from 1 to 100 000]

Comment: Well I was partially aware of this problem (I use Wolfram Alpha also) .So the question is what Desmos compute ? (+1)

Comment: You made a mistake $\operatorname{floor}\left(x+1\right)-x-1\leq 0$

Comment: I think the plot is correct until $n =200$

Comment: Not sure how good this tool supports long integers. PARI/GP might be a good tool as well. I do not understand the second comment , the picture shows no nonpositive values. And the gcd seems to behave chaotic , of course most entries are $1$.

Comment: @Peter It cannot be $n+2$ since we have the inequality .

Comment: OK, I think, I understand now. But for positive integers $x$ , the formula is actually correct.